# When should storyboards be used?

Tags: storyboard, xcode4.2

Is a storyboard a replacements for XIB views?

When should new XIB view be created separately vs having it added to a storyboard?

> To get view controllers for your storyboard, select Objects and
>   Controllers from the Object library (Figure 4-11) and drag the view
>   controllers you want onto the canvas...

This suggests, as i understand it, that we can add UIViewControllers directly to storyboard. Would you ever create XIB files outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, if you're using storyboards then there's not much need to create XIB files outside of the storyboard.  You could (optionally) use more than one storyboard but I struggle to see how even that would be useful.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for confirming